# Python BaseHTTPServer stops rest of script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using BaseHTTPServer to serve a simple variable, the problem is that the rest after `server.serve_forever()` is not executing.
It does not seem that BaseHTTPServer is forking?
How can i get around this problem?

The variable (http output) BaseHTTPServer is serving is continiously updated by the other part of the script.

Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/v4xEuHBs

Answer (score 0):

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import SocketServer
import os

def main():
  try:
    startserver(self)

def startserver(self):
    newpid = os.fork()
    if newpid == 0:
        server = HTTPServer(('',8080), ThreadingHTTPServer)
        server.serve_forever()

class ThreadingHTTPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            self.loop = loop
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('hello, world')
            return
```